# SPFレコードについて教えて下さい。

Tags: aws, dns, amazon-ec2

SPFレコードについて触れるようになり、調べていたところ、
こちらのサイト
https://sendgrid.kke.co.jp/blog/?p=3509
で、SPFレコードについて書かれてあったうちのSPFレコードの例なのですが、

```
v=spf1 ip4:198.51.100.1 include:example.com -all
```

この 198.51.100.1 というIPアドレスは具体的にはどのサーバのIPアドレスを設定すればよいのでしょうか？
また、 example.com も、送信したいドメインを設定すればよいのか、自分のドメインを設定すればよいのか、どちらでしょうか。

私は、お名前ドットコムで取得したドメイン (仮)example.net を
共有サーバSDのメールサーバで使用しています。
DNSは共有サーバSDにあります。

現在、AWSのEC2でサーバを立ち上げ example.net でアクセスできるようにしています。

DNS : 共有サーバSD? 
メールサーバ : 共有サーバSD
サイトを運営しているサーバ : EC2

ドメイン(仮) : example.net
EC2のIPアドレス(仮) : 203.0.113.1

上のような場合、EC2からどこかに(例えば***@gmail.comなど)メールを送信しようとした場合、SPFレコードはどのように設定すれば正しいでしょうか。

Comment: IPアドレスとドメインを例示用のものに編集しています

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SPFは"Sender Policy Framework"の略ですから、送信者(Sender)の情報を設定します。

> v=spf1 ip4:198.51.100.1 include:example.com -all

リンク先のブログに解説が書いてありますが、

- ip4 はそのレコードが設定されているドメインでメールを送信するサーバのIPアドレスの宣言
- includeはそこに指定されたドメインのSPFレコードを参照する宣言
- -allは無条件で認証を失敗させる宣言

になります。

203.0.113.1からexample.netドメインを発信者とするメールを送信する(そしてそれ以外のサーバからメールを送信することがない)場合、example.netに対するTXTレコードとして

```
v=spf1 ip4:203.0.113.1 -all
```

を設定します。

SPFは変な設定をしても他人に迷惑をかける事はまず無いですが、当然メールが届かないなどのトラブルになりますので、コピペではなくきちんと理解してから設定されることをお勧めします。

[インターネット協会が公開している解説](http://salt.iajapan.org/wpmu/anti_spam/admin/tech/explanation/spf/)は参考になると思います。